# SBT failing to resolve dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following simple SBT file

```
name := "TweetStream"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" %% "gson" % "2.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" %% "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4"
```

Somehow the SBT tool is adding a xxx_2.10 in the maven repository path resulting in unresolved dependencies as below.

```
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/hduser/workspace/TweetStream/}tweetstream...
[info] Resolving com.google.code.gson#gson_2.10;2.7 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.google.code.gson#gson_2.10;2.7
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/hduser/.ivy2/local/com.google.code.gson/gson_2.10/2.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson_2.10/2.7/gson_2.10-2.7.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson_2.10/2.7/gson_2.10-2.7.pom
[info] Resolving org.twitter4j#twitter4j-core_2.10;4.0.4 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.twitter4j#twitter4j-core_2.10;4.0.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/hduser/.ivy2/local/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core_2.10/4.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core_2.10/4.0.4/twitter4j-core_2.10-4.0.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core_2.10/4.0.4/twitter4j-core_2.10-4.0.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.google.code.gson#gson_2.10;2.7: not found
[warn]  :: org.twitter4j#twitter4j-core_2.10;4.0.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.google.code.gson:gson_2.10:2.7 (/home/hduser/workspace/TweetStream/build.sbt#L6-7)
[warn]        +- default:tweetstream_2.10:1.0
[warn]      org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core_2.10:4.0.4 (/home/hduser/workspace/TweetStream/build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:tweetstream_2.10:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.code.gson#gson_2.10;2.7: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.twitter4j#twitter4j-core_2.10;4.0.4: not found
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed Jun 30, 2016 11:45:29 PM
```

I have tried deleting the following ivy folder as suggested in another post, but it didn't help.

```
~/.ivy2/cache$ rm -r commons-logging/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't specify Scala version, and it defaults to 2.10, which is probably not what you want. I don't know if the dependencies you want are published for 2.10.

Another thing is, Gson is not published like a Scala library, so you should rather add it via single `%`. Not sure about twitter4j, but the name also suggests it's a Java, not Scala library. Try something like this in your `build.sbt`

```
name := "TweetStream"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8" // provide Scala version
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.7" // notice single `%` instead of `%%`
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4" // same here
```

Comment: Thank you Haspemulator. The single % definitely solved the problem. I believe scalaVersion spec should also be in double quotes like below

`scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`

Comment: @Maz indeed, fixed.